# Access cordova plugins in downloaded html files

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

I have a requirement where I need to download some HTML files from server and open them in the Cordova Webview.

I am facing challenge in accessing plugins from these downloaded files.

What path I need to put in my `<script>` tags of downloaded HTML file to access Cordova Plugin JS file packaged with the application under asset/www/ folder ?

Can I put file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js in my HTML?

Can I use loadDataWithBaseURL in place of loadURL ?

If not what will be its equivalent ?

Also need answer for iOS environment.

Need to answer this urgently.

**Update :**
I am loading my downloaded files like

```
loadUrl("file://"+pathToInternalStorage_Index.html");
```

Inside my HTML I have put

```
<script src="file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js></script>
```

Now when I open the downloaded file I get popup with EditText saying "gap_init:2"
and after clicking OK, I get error in console as CordovaWebview: TIMEOUT ERROR!

Error for Plugin is:
"Error : Method not found
....
.... (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:927:44)
....
....

Comment: Is this for an app that already uses cordova?  It sounds like you're downloading more than just raw HTML.  Are you downloading cordova plugins that require native code or just HTML + CSS + Javascript?

Comment: plugin Java file and other cordova JS all are already packaged and working.
I am downloading additional bundle with HTML/CSS/JS but they too use existing plugins. How can these plugins access Cordova ??

Comment: Can you give an example of a specific plugin you're trying to use and the Javascript code you're using to call it?  Also describing the precise behavior of the code for "normal" files vs "downloaded" files would be helpful.

Comment: its custom plugin... in JS I execute it like

cordova.exec(function(msg){console.log(msg);},function(err){console.log(err);},"PluginClassName","pluginName".[]);

I get error executing this line.

Comment: What's the error?  Is window.cordova not defined?

Comment: Steven,  Error is "ReferenceError : cordova is not defined at ....(pluginCall)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js></script>
```

Solved the issue. Also make sure cordova project is correctly build.